# Batch to move files in a folder to another folder?

Tags: windows, batch-file, move

I want to create a batch file that moves all the files in this directory to its father directory. Like for example if I have a directory " Something " that contains files :

...New Folder/Something

And I want to move the files in " Something " to New folder.

Is there such a command?

Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: A patch file or a *batch* file?

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant batch. What was I thinking?, really? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming you're talking about Windows batch files, `move *.* ..\` should do the trick.

**Edit:** For example, if you opened `cmd`, you could input:

```
cd C:\New Folder\Something
move *.* ..\
```

which would move all files in `C:\New Folder\Something` into its 'father' directory.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on that?

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible only if you don't have subdirectories, because move doesn't walk the subdirectories.
You can use xcopy with /E, however it will not delete the copied files and directories. Then you should use del *.*, but to delete the subdirectories you should call rd for each one, and that is not possible in batch files.